# How to prevent cookie from deleting is they're timed out?

Tags: browser

Maybe I ask in wrong section but maybe you can help me.

How to prevent cookie from deleting is they're timed out?

I'm talking about Firefox but in other browsers (like Chrome) if you have the answer the good.

Comment: The server will disregard your cookie once it expires. There is nothing you can do about it. This question is not about Ubuntu. Check Stackexchange's "SuperUser" website.

Comment: I thought maybe there is permission rules for that bitch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Cookies are given with an expiration time, and when they expire, the browser must delete them. That is how the specification works.